# Combine typing effect and end command on python3

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am new to python and am trying to figure out how to print text on separate lines with a break between them. I keep trying the below code and it does not work.

```
print("x")
print("x")
```

Comment: At least outline the following: 1) Input; 2) What you want done to the input; 3) Desired output.

Comment: I don't have a command really, but i am thinking something  along the lines of print("x", end="")            print("x"). Then I would like to have them spell out each letter, but with a stop after the first print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is does not have any specifics.
Perhaps you are looking to print multiple elements on the same line.

```
>>print(1,2,3,4,5,sep = ",",end = "\t")
1,2,3,4,5   >>>
```

Another Example

```
>>> print(1,2,3,4,5,sep = ":",end = "||\n")
1:2:3:4:5||
>>>
```

The sep is used to specify the separator between the different elements in the print statement. The default separator in python is " " a space.
The end is used to specify what should be printed at the end after all the elements.
The default one is "\n" which is the new line.

Comment: line_1 = “x ”
line_2 = “x ”
from time import sleep
import sys


for line in line_1:          
    for c in line:        
        print(c, end='')   
        sys.stdout.flush() 
        sleep(0.1)         
    print('')                                                                                              I do not know how to use the code link so i pasted in the comment.